# Apache Spark cheapest way to trigger a RDD transformation

Tags: java, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I'm totally new to Apache Spark and I've set up a standalone cluster to run a sorting algorithm for big amounts of data (Integer numbers).

I have it working the way I want. The core is as follows:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = ctx
                .parallelize(Collections.<Integer>emptyList(), PARTITIONS)
                .mapPartitions(partition ->
                        ThreadLocalRandom
                                .current()
                                .ints(NUMBERS_PER_PARTITION, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                                .boxed()

                                .parallel()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sortBy(x -> x, true, PARTITIONS);
```

This will generate random numbers in the cluster and then sort them.

The problem is that I am **only** interested in the sorting time for an experiment, but Spark is lazy and the sorting will only be triggered with a given action. I'm using `count()` to trigger the sorting, but it takes a very long time to finish the counting, therefore it delays my experiment. I don't care about getting the sorted numbers, or even a sample of it, since I already know it's sorting correctly.

Is there a way that I can trigger the `.sortBy()` without having to wait for the action that triggered it to finish? And if there isn't, is there a cheaper action than `count()`?

Comment: if you don't want it all run through you can just do a `take`. But if you are benchmarking, then the entire dataset needs to be run through I would think.

Comment: If I use `take(n)`, will the whole dataset be sorted or only the `n` elements I'm taking?
The same question goes for `first()`. I'm not sure if the whole collection is being sorted when using these methods.

Comment: When you do a sortBy and then take, then it supposes you take the N top elements, thus it has to sort everything and only then you can take some of it. Same thing with first. But even without sort first and (relatively small) take would lead to first partition to be fully processed.

Answer (score 0):

sort is a lazy spark transformations 
you can use one of the non lazy return values to trigger the action 
you already tried count which is taking a lot of time
try: first() or take(n)

Here is a list of lazy / non-lazy actions

https://www.mapr.com/ebooks/spark/apache-spark-cheat-sheet.html